# Unable to download dependency org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl for version [1.9.13]

Tags: maven, jackson

I wite you because I am having some issue with maven and jackson-core-asl dependency, and I hope you can help me.

Since this morning (15/4/2019) we are having problems in our CI because of the following error:

```
Failed to collect dependencies at org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:[1.9.13,1.9.13]: No versions available for org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:[1.9.13,1.9.13] within specified range -> [Help 1]
```

As long as it was happening in a big maven project, I’ve created the following mini pom.xml in order to figure out what was happening.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.davide</groupId>
    <artifactId>davide-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-app</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>[1.9.13]</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If you run `mvn clean install` against the previous pom , you will receive the aftermentioned error.

I am using the following maven configuration

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T20:49:05+01:00)
Maven home: /home/davide.pallaoro/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current
Java version: 1.8.0_171, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8.0.171-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

And I have no custom configuration in `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` (the file doe not exist in my machine)

But if you change the version from [1.9.13] to 1.9.13 or to [1.9.9] and run `mvn clean install` this will work correctly.
So it compiles when version is :

- 1.9.13
- 1.9.12
- 1.9.11
- [1.9.11]
- 1.9.10
- [1.9.10]
- 1.9.9
- [1.9.9]

And it does not compile when version is :

- [1.9.13]
- [1.9.12]

It seems that this problem started on Monday 15 April 2019, because on Friday 12 April 2019 we did not have those build problem and the project which we are working on did not change in the last days.

Do you know if something has changed in the last few days (from 12/4/2019 to 15/4/2019) about Jackson artifact in the public maven repos?

Many thanks for reading this and for your help, let me know in case you need any clarification.

Kind regards.

**EDIT**

Here is the output of the maven copilation
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QYH_FCYZ7_iS08cKrUO-UFDZ1oyTktUS 
(I put it in my drive because the output was too big and Stackoverlow did no let me add it to the post)

I've notices that in the maven central repo central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl the 2 versions that fails if exact [1.9.12] [1.9.13] have no date. Maybe this could be the reason ?

[maven central for jackson-core-asl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vq82.png)

Comment: Are you behind a proxy/corporate firewall etc. ? Do you use a repository manager ?

Comment: Your config seems to be correct. You could try to use Maven -X and -e options. The version lookup to match the range must fail.

Comment: The range is not the issue cause I can build without any issue....

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise I am not behind a proxy sever. And I've notices that in the maven central repo http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/ the 2 versions that fails if exact [1.9.12] [1.9.13]  have no date. Maybe this could be the reason ?
Thanks

Comment: @JensDibben I've updated the post with the output of maven

Comment: I can build this example project without any issue..apart from that I don't know why you are using a version range like `[1.9.13]` why not using `1.9.13` simply?

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise Version as `[1.9.13]` was presentin some legacy code, I guess it was like this because it was using something specific of version 1.9.13 and/or reise an error in case some other depedency will import a future version of the library that will not be backward comaptible.

Which version of maven and java are you using @khmarbaise ?

Comment: Maven 3.6.1 and JDK 8/11, my assumption is that you have a proxy/repository manager which does not work correctly but I can't say for sure cause you have not added the full error log output...

Comment: @khmarbaise you can find the log of `mvn clean install -e -X` here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QYH_FCYZ7_iS08cKrUO-UFDZ1oyTktUS
I could not add it to  the post because it was too large. Thank you agin for the support :)

Comment: Anyway I found pretty strange that only for the 2 version for which I have problem the date is empty in the maven central repo, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vq82.png Do you think that this could be related to my problem I am having ?  (Iv'e tried as well with maven 3.6.1 and the result was the same)